# Pandas undocumented DataFrame.keys() method

Tags: python, dictionary, dataframe, pandas, data-analysis

Im new in Pandas, and while playing with its `Dataframe`, i found method `keys()` which works pretty like `dict.keys()`. But I cannot find it in [docs](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/dev/api.html#dataframe). What am i missing?

Comment: There are quite a few methods/function which don't appear in the docs, `df.keys()` seems to be equivalent to `df.columns`... As to why, it could be because the source isn't correctly formatted to be read by sphinx, I'm not sure.

Comment: @AndyHayden: Actually, the source doesn't have a docstring at all.

Comment: @abarnert exactly! (?)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can see where this is defined in [the source](https://github.com/pydata/pandas/blob/master/pandas/core/frame.py#L708):

```
def keys(self):
    return self.columns
```

And, if you look at the git blame, you can see it was added as a fix for [#1240: "Request: keys() method on dataFrame"](https://github.com/pydata/pandas/issues/1240). The rationale seems to be:

> While learning Pandas this kind of method is useful to move from the well-understood dict structure to the more powerful DataFrame. As a pandas novice this kind of mental mapping would be much appreciated.

However, it's worth noting that `DataFrame` supports only about half of the mapping interface. For example, there's `iteritems` and `keys`, but no `iterkeys`. And there are also cases where they added similar but not-quite-the-same names, like `iterkv`, which is equivalent to `iteritems` but there specifically because the latter "gets incorrectly converted to .items() by 2to3".

You can go through the source and see where each of these were added and why, but there doesn't seem to be too much rhyme or reason beyond "`DataFrame` is kind of like a `dict`, and kind of not."

The fact that they chose not to document most of these methods, or to document that `DataFrame` is kind of like a `dict`, I wouldn't rely on any of this. Just use `columns` instead of `keys()`, etc.

Comment: Thank you for comprehensive answer!

Comment: Strange strategy by the way - writing something for novices and not documenting that.

Comment: @GillBates: I can understand the temptation. In a similar situation, I once checked in a function whose docstring said the equivalent of "joeschmoe wants this, he knows how to use it, nobody else cares", and 18 months after I stopped working on that project I got an email asking me how to contact Moe Joesch, and had to trade 3 emails before figuring out that someone was looking for how to use that function…

Comment: @GillBates: Meanwhile, you can always file a bug against the documentation. After all, if the rationale in #1240 was valid, surely documenting it is worthwhile—and probably documenting _all_ of the mapping-like methods, and maybe even documenting exactly how it is and is not like a mapping.

Comment: @GillBates, I assure you it wasn't an intentional strategy. Just the fact that we have lots to do and not enough time/people to do it :) Happy to take issues or PRs on documentation

Comment: @ChangShe: Is the intention that `DataFrame` actually be usable as a standard mapping? If so, it would be a lot easier to write a single patch to implement all the methods at once (possibly just by using `collections.MutableMapping`?), and then just document that it has all the standard mapping methods. (However, IIRC, you still don't get docstrings for many of the mixin-generated methods, at least in 2.x…)